# Resources for setting up socket communication on separate Linux machines , C++

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, local-network

I'll preface this question by saying that I'm pretty new to both Linux, and the C languages... so bear with me.

I'll also say that, I've asked a few of my friends that I consider to be knowledgeable along this subject, but they have also expressed confusion...

I've been tasked with trying to implement socket communication on a system of Linux machines. Currently, there is a host machine that uses two Intel Xeon Phi co-processors for additional computation power. Each of these co-processors actually has their own Linux kernel and I'm attempting to access them so I can take control over the automated load balancing mechanisms of the host machine. Basically, the end goal is to have control over which processes are handled by which co-processor.

Looking to do some pretty extensive calculations on heavy data sets regularly (every few seconds or less). Need to take in hundreds of thousands of data points, and perform bayesian mean regression using a variety of different parameters and data segmentations.

That being said, reliability is a must have... and each process that is being delegated will be fairly large (not brute forcing a simplistic and quick task).

I was hoping you all could make recommendations on (preferably free, online) resources that might be useful. Any recommendations will be appreciated.

Thanks,

James Elmore

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out tcpclient and tcpserver at the links below.  Basically, these handle all the sockets and networking, and you can focus on the core logic of your program.  Then, you would simply run your client program under tcpclient.  This will open a connection to the server.  Output from your program's stdout will be piped to the socket and sent to the server, and incoming input into the socket will be piped into the program's stdin.  Likewise, you would run your server program under tcpserver.  This will listen on a port for incoming connections.  After a connection is made, input to the socket will pipe to your program's stdin, and your programs output from stdout will be piped out through the socket.  See:
    http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpclient.html
    http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpserver.html

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider building some [Web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) (this may need to have C++ HTTP server libraries like [Onion](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion), the network part of [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/), or [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), and C++ HTTP client libraries, e.g. [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)).

You could also consider using the [Message Passing Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) (a.k.a. MPI).

Of course, you might look into [XMLRPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLRPC), [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), [JSONRPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_RPC), [ASN1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN1), [Corba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corba), [libs11n](http://s11n.net/s11n/), [ONC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call) (aka RPC-XDR), and [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) and [remote procedure call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) and [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) in general.

You could use shared memory or threads. Learn more about [pthreads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pthread), [NUMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Uniform_Memory_Access), [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) etc.

[Cloud computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing) might be also relevant, e.g. with [openstack](http://www.openstack.org/)

Specialized data-parallel languages (like [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/)) might be relevant too! Look also into [OpenMP](http://openmp.org), [Par4All](http://www.par4all.org/), [Pips4u](http://pips4u.org/) etc

Perhaps customizing the GCC compiler with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) might be relevant too!

Your question is a bit too broad. You should explain for which domain of parallel computing you are asking it. Latency, bandwidth, data size, reliability, etc... matters a lot.

Comment: Definitely data size and reliability. Looking to compute several million data points at a time being input every few seconds.

Comment: Please edit your question to improve it! Explain much more what kind of parallel computation you think about! Be specific, explain the domain....

Comment: I added some more information. Do you think that that is specific enough? I'm hesitant to divulge too much considering this is a corporate project.

Comment: It definitely helps. But I am not able to guide you more (I am a compiler & symbolic artificial intelligence guy, not at all expert in numerical processing). If your domain is related to Monte Carlo techniques, message passing is definitely relevant....